# mpg123 and Ruby; "Can't set terminal attributes"

Tags: ruby

I am playing a sound file stored locally on my computer in small program. The **program runs fine**, and the audio plays, however, **I keep getting a message on my terminal saying "Can't set terminal attributes"**.

I am using mpg123 and Ruby.
Hope you guys like DBZ :)

```
play_audio = fork{ exec 'mpg123','-q', '9000.mp3' }


h = { "Goku" => 9001, "Yamcha" => 4029, "Krillin" => 4034, "Piccollo" => 6701 }
puts "Vegeta, what does scouter say about his power level?\n\n"


h.each do |key, value|
    if value >  9000
        puts "#{key.upcase}'S POWER LEVEL IS OVER 9000!!!"
        play_audio
    else
        puts "#{key}'s power level is #{value}"
    end
end
```

A picture of the error message[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fork { exec 'mpg123','-q', '9000.mp3' }
```

What is the reason of `fork`ing a process here?

The forked process has no terminal and `mpg123` fails to set terminal attributes to output what it wants to output.

Possibly shutting it up might help:

```
fork { exec 'mpg123','-q', '9000.mp3', '>/dev/null', '2>&1' }
```

But still, just get rid of redundant `fork` and you are all set.

Comment: I think the point is to play the audio in the background while the rest of the script executes, so the fork is necessary. However silencing the error message is probably enough since it doesn't sound important.